# Thymeleaf String Template

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble working out what I'm doing wrong here -

```
@Test
void should_fill_a_string_template() {
    String template = "Hello ${name}";
    StringTemplateResolver resolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("name","Test");
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
    String result = templateEngine.process(template, context);
    Assertions.assertEquals("Hello Test",result);
}
```

I just want to use the Thymeleaf template processor in a plain old java project without other dependencies. I need to pass in a String (not a file to be resolved) and have the template filled with the values provided.

I see the default behavior [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.BETA02/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#process-java.lang.String-org.thymeleaf.context.IContext-) indicates that the StringTemplateResolver should just resolve the string passed in as the template itself and not a reference to the template.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `Hello ${name}` is not a Thymeleaf template. Can you try with `<div th:text="${name}"></div>` for example?

Comment: Yep, what you have works for me.  You just have to use a tag or expression that Thymeleaf will interpret -- for example, `"Hello [[${name}]]"` will also work and should pass your test..

Comment: yep /facepalm - wrong format for the template itself... Thanks Wim and Metroids!